# How do you position a gas valve correctly when connecting it to pipe?

Tags: plumbing

Say you have a valve where the control is on the side of the pipe, (perpendicular to flow).

The goal is to have the control facing you AND tightened to standard.

What is the way to achieve this without loosening it too much or tightening it too much?

Comment: What is the "standard" for tightening a threaded connection for gas piping? I assume this is for residential low pressure gas which is 7" W.C. (7 inches water column or about 0.25 psi). Some suppliers offer higher pressures (2 psi and 5 psi), but as I understand it this is rarely implemented and only in new construction not retrofit.

Comment: Yes .25psi.  I'm just speaking of using thread sealant, hand tighten + 2-3 turns for 3/4 in black pipe